# Error while using selectize.js: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2, selectize.js

I keep getting this error over again while using select.js for some reason I have checked other similar error it is still the same although I am doing this in flask jinja template and also have version 3.6.0 0f jquery installed and also got the selectize.js from the standalone folder I also tried the selectize.min.js is there any other JS needed? here is the error:

error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function
Tried code:

```
$(function() {
        $('select').selectize({
            sortField: "text"
        });
    });
also:



 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').selectize({
        sortField: "text"
        }
    });
    });
```

I even tried to rearrange my libraries, still same error.
HTML:

```
<select class="" name="">
        <option value="">sd</option>
        <option value="">sd</option>
        <option value="">sd</option>
        <option value="">sd</option>
    </select>
```

Please any advise on this or am missing something?

Comment: So sounds like you did not include selectize javascript code.

Comment: you may need to add an import for selectize. 
          <script type="text/javascript" src="selectize.js"></script>
see their docs https://selectize.dev/docs.html#installation

Comment: @epascarelloI got the selectize.js from the standalone folder and also the css  from the css folder, what other selectize javascript code am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So this finally worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('select').selectize();
});
```